# lambda function used in kinect

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

i was reading this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735666814) about kinect ,

and i have face a problem in this code :

```
void kinectSensor_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    SkeletonFrame frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame();
    if (frame == null)
        return;
    Skeleton[] skeletons ;
    skeletons = frame.GetSkeletons();
    if (skeletons.All(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked))
        return;
}
```

in this section :

```
if (skeletons.All(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked))
```

i want to know who provide the value of the parameter **s** in  the lambda exp above  ?

and also what `skeletons.All` mean and what it's return ?

Comment: s represents an item in skeletons.

Comment: Have you ever read anything about LINQ?  If you did some tutorials, or [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) you wouldnt have to ask

Comment: @maccettura no (*.*)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i edit the question can you help me in second question?

Comment: `skeletons.All` determines if all elements in `skeletons[]` satisfy a specific condition. In this case, the code is checking to see if all elements' `TrackingState` equal `SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked`. If all of them do, it will return `true`, else it will return `false`.

Comment: @trix0412 thanks you , i want to know is the return type is Boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `All` method accepts a `Func<Skeleton, bool>` and a `Func<Skeleton, bool>` is a delegate that encapsulates a method that accepts a `Skeleton` parameter and returns a `bool`.

You could define such a method yourself:

```
private bool YourMethod(Skeleton s)
{
    return s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked
}
```

...and pass this one to the `All` method:

```
if (skeletons.All(YourMethod))
```

`YourMethod` will be called for each `Skeleton` in `skeletons` and the `All` method will return `true` if `YourMethod` returns `true` for all those `Skeleton` objects.

`s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked` is an anonymous version of `YourMethod`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods